# Spring Boot Tomcat deployement not working Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, deployment

I trying to deploy my spring boot application in Tomcat 7 but i get this errors when i launch my Tomcat server :

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/phenix-doc-converter]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1018)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:994)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2021)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5693)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 10 more
```

My Pom.xml file :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Oddly when i'm deploying my war file in Tomcat 8 it work great !

Please, If there's any suggestion, do not hesitate.

Thank You !

PS :I'm working with JAVA 8

Comment: The reason why it is not working with Tomcat 7 is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49385703/5613727). In fact, this question is a duplicate but the question where the linked answer resides is marked as duplicate, too.The original question, however does not address this particular error while the linked answer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Main Problem is that: for Spring boot 2 The **minimum supported** version of Tomcat is **8.5**.

-*See more* ==> https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-20-new-features-infrastructure-changes

To work with Tomcat 7 we should downgrade Spring boot to 1.X (I don't recommend it)

-*See more*  about Spring boot 1.X requirement for Servlet containers ==> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html